# How to use Device.StartTimer to show grid and then call a function?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

So I have the following scenario: I have a grid that I wanted to show and hide using a timer. I have the following code so far:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
{
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
   {
      detailGrid.IsVisible = true;
      correctButton.IsEnabled = true;

      Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
      {
         Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
         {
            randomWords();
         });
         return false;
      });
    });
    return true;
});
```

What I am aiming is every 5 seconds I want the `detailGrid` to show and then wait another 5 seconds and will show a different random word and then the cycle continues.The code I have is not really working. It would show the `detailGrid` and then after 5 seconds would give random words once. The next runs would go straight to giving randoms words. Can anyone let me know how I can improve my code to do exactly what I wanted to do?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works:

```
int counter = 0;
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
{
    counter = counter + 5;
    if(counter%5==0)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            detailGrid.IsVisible = true;
            correctButton.IsEnabled = true;
        });
    }
    else
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            randomWords();
        });
    }

    return true;
});
```